# Django - How to cache AJAX result HTML block

Tags: ajax, django, caching

I have a search page that, by default lists products in a random order. Clicking a product lets you view it, and then there's a 'back' link which takes you back to the product list - this is saved in the random order using `{% cache %} <ul of results...</ul> {% endcache %}` with memcached. All works fine and well (have even a html comment cached @ h:i:s to check)!

The search has an ajax enhanced interface which does all the ajax-type-stuff you'd expect; it also updates the url to reflect exactly the same url that the non js search would do (behind the scenes communicating with this exact url, only with an /ajax/true/ flag in the url iteself).

When you use the ajax search even once to alter the results, for example set a country name, then click view product, when you click 'back' link the product ordering is back to random (as it has not been cached); the product set is saved though (generated from the url).

Is it possible to cache the result block using the django cache as ajax generates it, keeping the order and set exactly the same for when you hit that url again? or should I investigate other avenues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the results:

Example ajax search (with cache):

https://github.com/tomchuk/django-ajax-tasks/blob/master/example/templates/home.html

https://github.com/tomchuk/django-ajax-tasks/blob/master/ajax_tasks/templatetags/ajax_task.py

From django-ajax-tasks: https://github.com/tomchuk/django-ajax-tasks

Comment: Thanks - will give this a try and let you know :)